# How can I merge multiple xls sheets in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am working on a social media project and the excel file I have has multiple sheets. How do I merge the sheets to create a single df?

My machine is running Python v3 in Anaconda.
Please see the code below:

```
import pandas as pd 

xls = pd.ExcelFile('Digital Metrics Platforms_Clean.xlsx') 
df1 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'mar 2018')    
df2 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Dec 2018')
df3 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'Dec 2018')
df9 = pd.read_excel(xls, 'July 2019')
```

I ran the above code with no errors

---

```
dfs = [df.set_index('PlatformID') for df in [df1,df2, df3,df4,df5,df6,df7,df8,df9]]
df_merged = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).reset_index()
```

For the above, I expect the output to be a df with all the sheets merged onto one file called "df_merged", instead I get the following error message:

```
KeyError: "None of ['platformID'] are in the columns"
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that my sheets did not have the same number of columns, so ensuring that the data was in the same shape solved the problem